# No shadows when rendering very small objects

Tags: povray

I have a simple scene with a cylinder on a white plane, and two light sources that are far away at opposing angles. I'll be making thousands of these images with the light sources rotated or lowered a little bit each time, and the main purpose for each one is to have the shadows rendered for use in another experiment. The problem I'm running into is that when I make the object really small like on the order of 10^-5 (for the experiment I'll use the shadows in), I don't see any shadows from the object and the entire scene appears darker, as if the whole area were in a shadow. This occurs at any phi or theta I've tried.

At first I thought my camera might have been in the way, so I moved it back out and made the angle really small, yet the problem remained. I'm fairly new to POV-ray, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The question is why are there no shadows when the object becomes really small, and how can I fix it?

Here's my code:

```
#version 3.8;
global_settings{ assumed_gamma 1.0 }

#include "colors.inc"
#include "textures.inc"
#include "math.inc"

#declare Angle = 0.003;//45;
#declare Camera_Distance = 10;//7.9*pow(10,-4);

camera {
    orthographic
    location <0,Camera_Distance,0>
    look_at <0,0,0>
    angle Angle
}

light_source{<cos(phi)*sin(theta),cos(theta),sin(phi)*sin(theta)>*10000 color White}
light_source{<-cos(phi)*sin(theta),cos(theta),-sin(phi)*sin(theta)>*10000 color White}

plane{ <0,1,0>, 0
    texture{ pigment { color White }
    }
}

cylinder{<0,0,0>, <0,5*pow(10,-5),0>, 5*pow(10,-5)
    texture{ pigment { color Blue }
    }
}
```

Comment: Upon further examination, the shadows stop being rendered when the size of the cylinder changes between 10^-3 and 10^-4.